# Restfull webservice encryption and decryption

Tags: security, encryption

Client will send me data in the form of XML and JSON and I need to built service which store this data into database.For security purpose we want to get in the form of encryption and our backend is in java script we want to decrypt it in JavaScript. Client request can come either from PHP, Java, C# etc. Do you know any standard algorithm which has implementation in all popular languages and we can use for this project. We already implementation of DES algorithm in our system. If will be fine if there will be implementation of this algorithm in all other languages. If any one of you please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an https link? This will transparently encrypt the complete session and is available on all platforms.